# R: NA Issue with checking if all elements in column are the same

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean, na

There are several threads asking how to check if all elements in a vector are the same. That is not my issue.

I have been using the `all` function in `R` with no issues. I wanted to assess if all elements of a column `mydataframe$colA` are the same as in `mydataframe$colB`:

`if(all(mydataframe$colA == mydataframe$colB) == FALSE) {...}`

However today I started to see `NA` as being returned as result of the `all` function, instead of a boolean. I have tried other ways to find if all elements are the same or not. For example:

`table(mydataframe$colA == mydataframe$colB)` gives me only `TRUE`

So indeed all my values from column A are the same as the ones in column B.

What can be wrong here? I stress that my script has been working fine, and even today I ran these same lines 8 times before with data from different samples with no problem. All data and all samples are supposed to be in the exact same format of each other.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like one of your variables has an NA value. what is the result of `table(mydataframe$colA == mydataframe$colB, useNA="ifany")`?

Comment: Try this:  `table(mydataframe$cola, useNA="ifany")` and also for colB

Comment: Or use `anyNA(mydataframe$cola)` for considering a single variable.

Comment: Read the help page for `?table` more cerefully than you have so far.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Indeed one NA was introduced somehow in the previous steps. Just need to find out why.